# How to know when to use document.body

Tags: javascript

I have a simple scroll function which allows me to smooth scroll to an element with an id.

When I call the function I set a boundary, which is usually the `<body>` tag.

Example call:

```
scrollToPos(document.body, howfar, 200);
```

The problem is that some browsers use `document.body` and others use `document.documentElement`

Is there a way I can know which to use without doing a mass browser checking?

I'm using Javascript, but not Jquery

Comment: `if (document.body) {
/* use document.body */
} else if (document.documentElement) {
/* use document.documentElement */
}`

Comment: This is essentially a problem with old browsers (ie 6-8, opera < 9, etc.) wich browsers are you targeting ?

Comment: @Epsilon That doesn't work, document.body must exist even if not used

Comment: @ClemSndr Its definitely not a problem with just old browsers, FF and Chrome are different for example in their latest versions

Comment: @ClemSndr Well, it works on new versions of browsers. For old browsers `typeof(document.body)!="undefined"` could be helpful.

Comment: @ClemSndr Thanks, but its never undefined afaik, its an object in all browsers